# Query insert fail, codeigniter oracle

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I have this query, thrown by the debug codeigniter

```html
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number:

INSERT INTO "SALUD"."POS_EMPLEOS" ("EMPLEO_EST_ID", "EMP_FECHA_PUBLICACION", "EMP_FECHA_FINALIZA", "EMP_DESCRIPCION", "EMP_VACANTES", "EMP_EXP_MINIMA", "CARGO_TIPO_ID", "AREA_PROFESIONAL_AREA_ID", "CALIDAD_JURIDICA_CAL_ID", "EST_CODIGO", "EMP_TITULO") VALUES ('1', '17/02/2015', '28/02/2015', 'Programador PL/SQL Oracle', '1', '6 Anos', '2', '12', '1', '100', 'Database Analyst')

Filename: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11\data\localweb\projects\recluta-igniter\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 331
```

controller:

```html
    public function grabar_convocatoria(){
        
    $titulo         = $this->input->post("titulo_oferta");
    $descripcion    = $this->input->post("descripcion");
    $fecha_finaliza = $this->input->post("fecha_finaliza");
    $vacantes       = $this->input->post("vacantes");
    $experiencia    = $this->input->post("sel_experiencia");
    $tipo_cargo     = $this->input->post("sel_tipo_cargo");
    $area_prof      = $this->input->post("sel_area_prof");
    $calidad_j      = $this->input->post("sel_cal_jur");
    $establecimiento= "$this->cod_estab";

    $resultado = $this->model_empleos->set_empleo($titulo,$descripcion,
                                                    $fecha_finaliza,$vacantes,
                                                    $experiencia,$tipo_cargo,
                                                    $area_prof,$calidad_j,
                                                    $establecimiento);
        
        if($resultado){
            redirect("ctrl_editor/publicar_convocatoria");
        }else{
            $datax["data"] = $resultado;
            $this->load->view("view_test",$datax);
        }
        
    }
```

Model:

```html
    public function set_empleo($titulo,$descripcion,$fecha_finaliza,$vacantes,
                                $experiencia,$tipo_cargo,$area_prof,$calidad_j,
                                $establecimiento){
        

        $data = array(
        'EMP_FECHA_PUBLICACION' => '17/02/2015',
        'EMP_FECHA_FINALIZA' => $fecha_finaliza,
        'EMP_DESCRIPCION' => $descripcion,
        'EMP_VACANTES' => $vacantes,
        'EMP_EXP_MINIMA' => $experiencia,
        'CARGO_TIPO_ID' => $tipo_cargo,
        'AREA_PROFESIONAL_AREA_ID' => $area_prof,
        'CALIDAD_JURIDICA_CAL_ID' => $calidad_j,
        'EST_CODIGO' => $establecimiento,
        'EMP_TITULO' => $titulo
        );
        
        $this->db->set("EMPLEO_EST_ID",'1');
        $this->db->insert("SALUD.POS_EMPLEOS",$data,FALSE);
        
     if($this->db->affected_rows() == 1)
      {
        return true;
      }
      else
      {
        
        return $this->db->last_query();
      } 


    }
```

I have tried multiple ways to make the insert. in my project there are many inserts, only this is what gives problems.

Please Help me!

//***** edit *** //

Solution : 
TO_CHAR(FIELD,'dd/mm/yyyy') AS DATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dates are not formated correctly

Convert them in US format :

```
$timestamp = '20/02/2015';
$timestamp = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y', $timestamp);
$gooddate  = date_format($timestamp, 'Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Yes I know, I'm in France and it's the same. However, DBMS work only with US format so we have to convert them before inserting.

Comment: Thanks AdrienXL , my dates are not formated correctly. Solution : TO_CHAR(FIELD,'dd/mm/yyyy') AS DATE

Comment: Did you you solved your issue then ? Also, if the answer helped, please mark it as accepted.